# Is string actually an array of chars or does it just have an indexer?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

As the following code is possible in C#, I am intersted whether string is actually an array of chars:

```
string a="TEST";
char C=a[0]; // will be T
```

Comment: i'd guess it will depend on the implementation. have a look inside the string class with reflector

Comment: It's a good idea not to bother how the string is internally represented. Microsoft's implementation may differ from Mono's, which may differ from the Compact Framework's... Program against the interface(s) not the internals :)

Answer (score 23):

`System.String` is not a .NET array of `char`, because this will compile:

```
char[] testArray = "test".ToCharArray();

testArray[0] = 'T';
```

but this will not:

```
string testString = "test";

testString[0] = 'T';
```

Char arrays are mutable, Strings are not.

Also, `string is Array` returns false, while `char[] is Array` returns true.

Answer (score 17):

No, it's not an array. But it does have an indexer. Best of both worlds.

Comment: stretchy?  What does that mean?

Comment: Stretchy, like an elastic band.</tongueincheek>

Comment: I meant you don't have to declare it with the fixed size.

Comment: They do have fixed sizes though.  It's not possible to resize a string, so they don't seem all that stretchy to me.

Comment: Okay, removed this confusing passage.

Comment: "string", strictly speaking, is syntactic sugar for a character "vector". It is an object that stores the reference to the start of a null-terminated set of characters. An instance of a string, meaning the set of characters in memory, is immutable; what looks like you changing the string (appending, capitalization, replacement, etc) actually results in a new instance of the string being created and its reference put into the string, and the old string is GCed. This is why constructs like StringBuilder, which keep the data in a more mutable state while building a string, are good practice.

Comment: @KeithS good comment but I can't help this.. strictly speaking C# strings aren't a vector (at least in the C++ sense) nor are they null terminated.

Comment: @keithS .net strings may have embedded bills.

Answer (score 7):

Strings in .NET are backed by the `System.String` class, which internally uses a bunch of unsafe methods to do pointer manipulation on the actual string data using standard C memory manipulation techniques.

The `String` class itself does not contain an array, but it does have an indexer property which allows you to treat the data as if it were an array.

Answer (score 6):

To add a little to Scott Dorman's and Gufa's answer. If you use **Windbg** and `!DumpObject` on the string `abcd` you'll get somthing like this.

```
0:000> !do 01139b24
Name: System.String
MethodTable: 79330a00
EEClass: 790ed64c
Size: 26(0x1a) bytes
 (C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
String: abcd
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
79332c4c  4000096        4         System.Int32  1 instance        5 m_arrayLength
79332c4c  4000097        8         System.Int32  1 instance        4 m_stringLength
793316e0  4000098        c          System.Char  1 instance       61 m_firstChar
79330a00  4000099       10        System.String  0   shared   static Empty
    >> Domain:Value  00181b38:01131198 <<
79331630  400009a       14        System.Char[]  0   shared   static WhitespaceChars
    >> Domain:Value  00181b38:011318b8 <<
```

You'll notice its only got three instance fields. `m_arrayLength`, `m_stringLength` and `m_firstChar`. It does not contain an instance `System.Char[]`. The other 2 fields are static shared so every `System.String` has the same `Empty` string and `WhitespaceChars` char Array.

If you follow that with a **DumpByte** you'll see the string data (in this case `abcd`) that's in the heap which of course starts at offset `0x0c` (`m_firstChar`) and is **8 bytes wide** (`m_stringLength` **4 x 2** for unicode).

```
0:000> db 01139b24 L1A

01139b24  00 0a 33 79 05 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 61 00 62 00  ..3y........a.b.
01139b34  63 00 64 00 00 00 00 00-00 00                    c.d......
```

If you were to look in the SSCLI you'll see that it, as Scott says, either runs unsafe code and uses pointer techniques to read the data using the `m_firstChar` and the `m_stringLength`.

Comment: I appreciate your delicate, detailed explanation.

May I ask how DumpByte works? I am somewhat a newbie to such advanced features, debugging or reverse-techniques. Does it depend on debugging data or, does it work in non-debugging mode? If it works in non-debugging mode, how does it get another program's memory data?

Comment: @SmartHumanism the way I used WinDbg was based on a full memory dump files. This dump analysis relied on SoS (son of strike) WinDbg extensions. I'm pretty sure that SoS was what resolved the class name System.String but it's been a long time since I've done this and I don't know what the current state is for debugging tools.

Comment: I appreciate your answering comment. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

String is a class which takes an array of char to initialized itself, So when you try to fetch the element at some index it returns char. 
Check the string class

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.String class to the value indicated
        //     by an array of Unicode characters.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   value:
        //     An array of Unicode characters.
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public String(char[] value);
    }
```

Also see String class declaration.

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
```

Which is inherited by `IEnumerable<char>`.

**Inside the string class there is a get property which returns the char when index is passed, see the image. Which clearly says that Gets the System.Char object at a specified position in the current System.String**

```
public char this[int index] { get; }
```

Comment: Please don't answer things with code included as pictures. Looking at your answer, it should function perfectly if you copy those blocks of code properly to the answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for your feedback, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A `string` is not a `char[]`, although it does have a `.ToCharArray()`.  Also it does have an indexer, which allows you to access characters individually, like you've shown.  It is likely that it was implemented with an array internally, but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

No, String is a class in .Net.  It may be backed by an array. but it is not an array.  Classes can have indexers, and that is what String is doing.

**See comments for elaboration on this statement:**  From what I understand, all strings are stored in a common blob.  Because of this, "foo" and "foo" point to the same point in that blob... one of the reasons strings are immutable in C#.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the fact that equivalent strings are the same reference though, as I don't think it's guaranteed in general.

Comment: It's called string interning.

Comment: Agreed.  Never rely on internal implementation details.  They always reserve the right to change.  I added that note because the OP seemed to be interested in knowing how `String` works.

Comment: What is meant by common blob? Can you cite a source for this?

Comment: @Conrad Frix: As @Developer Art stated, it is called string interning.  Here is more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

Comment: @Brian. My understanding was that not all strings are interned. If they were string.IsInterned() probably wouldn't exist. So perhaps your answer should read "some strings are stored in a common blob. Because of this  "foo" and "foo" might point to the same point in that blob...

Comment: @Conrad Frix: According to this article, C# and VB.NET intern their strings by default, but it is not a .Net default... other languages could choose to do it differently, which is why the "interned" methods exist on string.  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx

Comment: @Brain the article says that literals are interned. Not all strings are literals. For example StringBuilder().Append("wx").Append("yz").ToString();

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Awesome.  I love SO.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

A string object contains a continuous block of characers, just like an array of characters, but the string object neither is, nor contains an array object.

The compiler knows that the string string is immutable, so it can do certain optimisations when you access a string, in the same manner that it does optimisations when you access an array. So, when you access a string by index, it's likely that the code ends up accessing the string data directly rather than calling an indexer property.

Answer (score 2):

Strings is simply not an array, in the sense that `"Hello" is char[]` is evaluated to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

A `string` is not an array of `char`s until you convert it to one. The notation is simply used to access characters at different positions (indices) in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com), we can see that string does implement `IEnumerable<char>`. So, it is not a character array, but in essence can be used like one.

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
```

**EDIT:**

Implementing `IEnumerable<char>` does not mean that the type will be indexed. I didn't mean to convey that. It means that you can enumerate over it and use it like a collection.  A better way of wording what I meant to say is that a string isn't a character array, but is a collection of characters. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: This is somewhat inaccurate. An `IEnumerable<char>` isn't what allows the indexer to be used on strings. If you needed to access an element from any `IEnumerable<T>` you would have to use the `ElementAt` method; an indexer wouldn't be available to other object types (`T`) simply by implementing `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has given half the answer, so here is both parts:

1) Strictly speaking, yes, a String in .NET is an array of characters. It is so both in its internal implementation, and by the symantic definition of an array.

2) However String is, as others have pointed out, somewhat peculiar. It is not a System.Array as all other arrays are. So in the strict, .NET specific way, a String is not an Array.