# How are String and Char types stored in memory in .NET?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, clr

I'd need to store a language code string, such as "en", which will always contains 2 characters.

Is it better to define the type as "String" or "Char"?

```
private string languageCode;
```

vs

```
private char[] languageCode;
```

Or is there another, better option?

How are these 2 stored in memory? how many bytes or bits for will be allocated to them when values assigned?

Comment: Have you actually proved to yourself that this is a problem yet? I've only very rarely found the need to worry about memory when using strings - especially such small ones. If it isn't showing up as a problem then don't worry about it until it is. It's an easy fix at a later date if strings are causing you a memory issue. Otherwise use a string and dont even think about memory issues.

Comment: I have a very intense logic which stores thousands of these in memory so every little helps.

Comment: @William If performance is that critical, why not declare an `enum LanguageCode : short` and save 2 bytes?

Comment: There would be up to 20 combinations. Not sure how such enum is stored in memory or if it's better?

Comment: @William in that case, go for `byte`, it takes 1 byte. I've updated my answer. Enums are value types and will exist on the stack when in method scope, or inside the heap space of a class in class scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How They Are Stored**

Both the `string` and the `char[]` are stored on the heap - so storage is the same. Internally I would assume a `string` simply is a cover for `char[]` with **lots** of extra code to make it useful for you.

Also if you have lots of repeating strings, you can make use of [Interning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) to reduce the memory footprint of those strings.

**The Better Option**

I would favour string - it is immediately more apparent what the data type is and how you intend to use it. People are also more accustomed to using strings so maintainability won't suffer. You will also benefit greatly from all the boilerplate code that has been done for you. Microsoft have also put a lot of effort in to make sure the `string` type is not a performance hog.

**The Allocation Size**

I have no idea how much is allocated, I believe strings are quite efficient in that they only allocate enough to store the Unicode characters - as they are immutable it is safe to do this. Arrays also cannot be resized without allocating the space in a new array, so I'd again assume they grab only what they need.

[Overhead of a .NET array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array)

**Alternatives**

Based on your information that there are only 20 language codes and performance is key, you could declare your own enum in order to reduce the size required to represent the codes:

```
enum LanguageCode : byte
{
    en = 0,
}
```

This will only take 1 byte as opposed to 4+ for two `char` (in an array), but it does limit the range of available `LanguageCode` values to the range of `byte` - which is more than big enough for 20 items.

You can see the size of value types using the `sizeof()` operator: `sizeof(LanguageCode)`. Enums are nothing but the underlying type under the hood, they default to `int`, but as you can see in my code sample you can change that by "inheriting" a new type.

Comment: You don't explicitly intern strings in .Net; they're interned for you implicitly by their mere declaration. In addition, strings and char arrays are extremely different in .Net, given that char arrays are mutable structures on the heap, or even the stack depending on how you declared them, while strings are immutable and as the article you linked to notes, build up and build up and build up in the intern pool rather than the regular .Net Framework memory - meaning they can be very wasteful.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Not all strings are interned. Literals are interned, but nothing much else is. If you take a string an input, read it from a resource file or another source they are not interned. You have to intern them manually. Interestingly, my answer didn't even state either way.

Comment: That depends on how the code is written - for example if it's searching for a bunch of string bits declared in the code, you nonetheless end up with a bunch of interned strings. But the important performance concern is throwing a ton of unnecessary intermediary strings on the heap when you know you don't need them - a single char array is always going to be much cheaper memory-wise, and if you write your code similar to the internals of Regex, cheaper CPU-wise. Less mem used in .Net means less GC too, which has another CPU benefit.

Comment: @chris Indeed but that relies on an array that likely won't resize, such as the language code in the question. However in the case of the question itself I'd actually suggest bypassing all this and using an enumerated value.

Comment: After reading the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669199/c-sharp-is-string-actually-an-array-of-chars-or-does-it-just-have-an-indexer I am lil confused how the link is stored internally

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Use string

Long answer:

```
private string languageCode;
```

AFAIK strings are stored as a length prefixed array of chars. A String object is instantiated on the heap to maintain this raw array. But a String object is much more than a simple array it enables basic string operations like comparison, concatenation, substring extraction, search etc

While

```
private char[] languageCode;
```

will be stored as an Array of chars i.e. an Array object will be created on the heap and then it will be used to manage your characters. But it still has a length attribute which is stored internally so there are no apparent savings in memory when compared to a string. Though presumably an Array is simpler than a String and may have fewer internal variables thus offering a lower memory foot print (this needs to be verified).

But OTOH you loose the ability to perform string operations on this char array. Even operations like string comparison become cumbersome now. So long story short use a string!

Answer (score 1):

> How are these 2 stored in memory? how many bytes or bits for will be allocated to them when values assigned?

Every *instance* in .NET is stored as follows: one `IntPtr`-sized field for the type identifier; one more for locking on the instance; the remainder is instance field data rounded up to an `IntPtr`-sized amount. Hence, on a 32-bit platform every *instance* occupies 8 bytes + field data.

This applies to both a `string` and a `char[]`. Both of these also store the length of the data as an IntPtr-sized integer, followed by the actual data. Thus, a two-character `string` and a two-character `char[]`, on a 32-bit platform, will occupy 8+4+4 = 16 bytes.

The only way to reduce this when storing exactly two characters is to store the actual characters, or a struct containing the characters, in a field or an array. All of these would consume only 4 bytes for the characters:

```
// Option 1
class MyClass
{
    char Char1, Char2;
}

// Option 2
class MyClass
{
    CharStruct chars;
}
...
struct CharStruct { public char Char1; public char Char2; }
```

`MyClass` will end up using 8 bytes (on a 32-bit machine) per instance plus the 4 bytes for the chars.

```
// Option 3
class MyClass
{
    CharStruct[] chars;
}
```

This will use 8 bytes for the MyClass overhead, plus 4 bytes for the `chars` *reference*, plus 12 bytes for the array's overhead, plus 4 bytes per `CharStruct` in the array.

Comment: Interesting.  Where did you get this information from though?

Comment: @kristianp Much of this information comes from this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx (scroll down to Figure 6)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store exactly 2 chars, and do it most efficiently, use a struct:

```
struct Char2
{
 public char C1, C2;
}
```

Using this struct will generally not cause new heap allocations. It will just upsize an existing object (by the minimum possible amount) or consume stack space which is very cheap.

Comment: Heap allocations will depend entirely on *where* you declare the struct. It will only be on the stack if declared inside methods / properties. Inside classes it will be in the heap, with the rest of the class members.

Comment: It will not cause a *new* allocation. It will just upsize an existing object (by the minimum possible amount).

Comment: Yes true, but heap allocations are typically very fast and shouldn't initially be worried about. That said, a struct of `struct LanguageCode` is a good option.

Comment: Why is he asking about performance, then? Maybe he needs to store a billion of those strings. This is a perf question and I answer it as such.

Comment: He isn't asking about performance, the word doesn't feature once. He is asking how they are stored and which is preferred, you only answer the latter indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Strings indeed have a size overhead of one pointer length, i.e. 4 bytes for a 32 bit process, 8 bytes for a 64 bit process. But then again, strings offer so much more in return than char arrays.

If your application uses many short strings and you don't need to use their string properties and methods that often, you could probably safe a few bytes of memory. But if you want to use any of them as a string, you will first have to create a new string instance. I can't see how this will help you safe enough memory to be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

String just implements an indexer of type char internally and we can say that `string` is just equivalent to `char[]` type with lots of extra code to make it useful for you, hence, like an array, it is stored on heap always.

An array cannot be manipulated without allocating it new space, same will be the case of a string hence, it is immutable

String implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Noticeable point: When you pass a string to a function, it is a **pass by value** unless there is a use of `ref`