# Modification of strings

Tags: c#, string, immutability

I understand that strings are an immutable reference type in C#. But I have a more specific question.

```
string a = "hello ";
string b = a;
a += "world";
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The code above will produce the output `hello`. I realize that this is because strings are immutable so once we have created an instance of a string with the value "hello " it cannot be modified. But I want to know, what happens when we do `a += "world"` ? Looking at the IL doesn't seem to give me the whole story unfortunately (or it might be that I am too novice to see the bigger picture)

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "hello "
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0008:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_000A:  ldstr       "world"
IL_000F:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_0014:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0015:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0016:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

The IL reveals to me what I had already guessed that the string "hello " is concatenated into with "world" to form a new string. But does this mean that what this line actually does is to:

1. Create a new instance of a string object with the value "world".
2. Read the value of our first string object "hello" and then concatenate that value with "world" to form a third string.
3. Return the reference of aforementioned string to `a`.
4. The "world" string instance is now orphaned and marked for collection?

Or am I completely wrong here? I really want to know what's going on "behind the scenes" or so to say..

Comment: No you are not wrong at all. You basically answered your question yourself. That is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because strings are immutable one equivalent to your program is:

```
string a = "hello ";
string b = a;
a = new string(a + "world");
```

Because strings are immutable the `new` operator is basically included for you.

In case you were interested, internally strings are stored as character arrays ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx)). They are actually stored on the heap which is why careful use of strings is important (heap memory isn't unlimited). I also found this other relevant stack question here: [How are String and Char types stored in memory in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782690/how-are-string-and-char-types-stored-in-memory-in-net)

Comment: Right, so in total we have actually created 3 seperate instances of a string object in this program? A the original (hello), "world" and a + "world" ("hello world") ?

Comment: @OverlyExcessive Yup! Every time you declare a string, or use a string in a statement, or even use a string operation (`+`, `+=`), the .NET runtime creates another string on the heap. The only exception would be any places the compiler optimizes and concatenate strings as part of compilation.

Comment: Strings in .NET are *not* null-terminated.  If they were, they wouldn't be able to contain `'\0'` characters (which they most certainly can).

Comment: @Kyle My bad on that. I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `a += "world";` really does what you puzzled out, being equivalent to `a = a + "world";`.

That's a case of `+=` being strictly only syntactic sugar. Still, who doesn't like some sweets?

Answer (score 1):

When you write `a += "world"` is as you were writing `a = a + "world"`, which actually creates a new string from the concatenation of the strings `a` and `"world"` and then assigns the result to the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `a+="World"`, it creates a new string with the value `a + "world"`. Since `hello` is still being used by `b`, it is not yet garbage collected.